# I used my school account to use Office 365. Can my school control my device now?

Tags: account-security, rat

Whilst I was setting up Office 365, there was an option that said "allow my organization to manage my device". I unchecked it, but I can still access their network drives.

- Does this mean they now have control over my home laptop? I did not download any software from them except to activate word using that account.
- If I had checked the box then what could they do?
- If they have control over my device, what I can I do to disable this and regain sole control over my device?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackExchange. I want to ask for clarification on your question. Did you mean you can access their "network drives" or "network drivers"? Those are two entirely different things. I suggested an edit on your question, but left this part verbatim as to not change the meaning of what was originally asked. Please [edit] the question yourself if you meant to write "network drives".

Comment: This has been answered over on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1389119/106273).